# spring-security-samples-preauth-xml example fails to run

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-security

Project:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples/preauth-xml

When trying to run the project above, I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#ec8a0ac': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'fsi' while setting constructor argument with key [4]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fsi' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SUPERVISOR, ROLE_USER]
```

XML code related to the error:

```
<bean id="fsi" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="httpRequestAccessDecisionManager"/>
        <property name="securityMetadataSource">
            <sec:filter-security-metadata-source>
                <sec:intercept-url pattern="/secure/extreme/**" access="ROLE_SUPERVISOR"/>
                <sec:intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
                <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
            </sec:filter-security-metadata-source>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Tried running it on tomcat 6 and 7, the same error occurs. Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample was not properly migrated to Spring Security 4. I logged a bug ([SEC-2966](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2966)) and [fixed it](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/7b158d05258340c944cabadeb0b183c7b4a0f210#diff-a7fe380061e04d29d799333bdce5bde7L78). The problem is that the use-expression attribute in Spring Security 4 was changed to be true by default. So we need to explicitly state it as false:

```xml
<sec:filter-security-metadata-source use-expressions="false">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/secure/extreme/**" access="ROLE_SUPERVISOR"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
</sec:filter-security-metadata-source>
```

Comment: Thank you, Rob. Thought I was going mad for a second!

Comment: Good answer, helped out as well for me

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this was the issue I was facing. But I made use-expressions="true" and changed access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER')" which did not work and got the same error.

I would assume using use-expressions="true" should work when you change access to use hasAnyRole or hasRole. It did not work for me.

It worked when I changed the use-expressions="false" and then access="ROLE_USER"

strange..

Thanks Rob